# Cannot SSH/RDP until after pinging URL

Tags: ssh, dns, ping

If, after starting system (freshly installed Linux Mint 13), I try to run:

```
ssh mywebsite.com
```

it hangs up with "Connection timed out". but when I open the browser and enter `mywebsite.com` there (or even run `ping`), SSH suddenly starts working.

The same happens with one program accessing it's API through HTTPS. I cannot use it until I access API through the browser. The same happens with RDP protocol. `remmina`/`rdesktop` don't work until I ping specific URL.

There are no iptable rules/firewalls on the computer/router. There is only NAT on the router, that's all. Might this be DNS related? What can i do to debug/fix this issue?

Comment: A routing problem? What does `netstat -rn` show?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing connection type to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" and specifying dns servers inside the connection. I suppose issue was with DNS or the router.